# Mapping a square from the $Z$ plane into the $W$ plane under the transformation $w=\frac{1}{z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have solved the following problem, but I am not sure if my solution is correct.

> A square $S$ has vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$.
>
> **Part 1:** Determine the region in the $W$ plane which $S$ is mapped under the transformation $w=\frac{1}{z+1}$.
>
> **Part 2:** Same transformation but now change the vertices to $(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1)$.

My solution which I want to check is this:

For the first part I get circles with center $\frac 12$ and $-\frac12$ (on the $v$ axis), the radius for those circles is $\frac12$. I also get a circle of center $\frac14$ on the $u$ axis with radius $\frac14$. I shaded the region inside the circles. For **Part 2** I get a circle with center $-\frac12$ on the $v$ axis and one with center $\frac12$ on the $u$ axis. The radius here is $\frac12$. I also shaded these regions.

Comment: So give your solution as part of your question.  Also, give some thought to why the second question might be different.

Comment: can you break up the transformation $w = \frac{1}{z+1}$ into  simpler transformations:(a) translation, (b) inversion, (c) reflection on the $x$-axis? it would be easier to find the image of the sides under the simple transformations.

Answer (score 0):

when we move from $(0,0) \rightarrow (1,0)$ then $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $y=0$ under the given transformation $w=\dfrac{1}{z+1}=\dfrac{x+1-iy}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$

then $0\leq x\leq 1\implies 1\leq x+1\leq 2\implies 1\geq\dfrac{1}{x+1}\geq \dfrac{1}{2}$ Thus under the transformation if $w=u+iv$ then $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq u\leq 1$ and $v=0$

again when $0\leq y\leq 1$

$\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}-i\dfrac{y}{1+y^2}$ provided $x=0$

Hence the real part $0\geq \frac{-y}{1+y^2}\geq \dfrac{-1}{2}$

and the imaginary part $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq \dfrac{1}{1+y^2}\leq 1$.Now can you find the rest

Comment: please See my answer above ,I have found the regions which are circles, I am just not sure if my solution is correct

Comment: Can we assume that by the "W plane" you mean the compplex projective line and that the map is $z \mapsto (1:z+1)$?